# How to save Many-To-Many relationship that uses custom class for ID

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I have a custom classID `UserId` and `OrganizationId`. Ii allows me to create a string-like id with prefixes `USER-1234` and `Org-1234` instead of a random string.

Now I have the following two classes that are supposed to have `many-to-many` relationship:

```
@Entity('user')
export class User {
  @PrimaryColumn({
    type: 'varchar',
    transformer: idTransformer,
  })
  @Property()
  id: UserId;

  ...
  @ManyToMany(() => Organization, (org) => org.users)
  @Default([])
  @JoinTable({ name: 'user_organization' })
  organizations: Array<Organization>;
}

@Entity('organization')
export class Organization {
  @PrimaryColumn({
    type: 'varchar',
    transformer: idTransformer,
  })
  @Property()
  id: OrganizationId;
  
  ...
  @ManyToMany(() => User, (user) => user.organizations)
  @JoinTable({ name: 'user_organization' })
  @Default([])
  users: Array<User>;
}
```

Where `idTransformer` is

```
export const idTransformer = {
  to: (value: Id) => {
    return value.getValue();
  },
  from: <T extends Id>(value: string): T => {
    if (value) {
      return IdUtils.fromHex(value);
    }

    return null;
  },
};
```

I can get the joins when I do a fetch, assuming I have manually entered the data into the database. However, when I try to "save" using

```
const org = await orgRepository.getOrg();
const user = await getUser();
org.users.add(user);

await orgRepository.save(org);
```

I get the following error:

```
  error: {
    name: 'QueryFailedError',
    message: "Field 'organizationId' doesn't have a default value",
    status: 500,
    errors: [],
    stack: "QueryFailedError: Field 'organizationId' doesn't have a default value\n" +
```

Looking at MySQL Logs, I see

```
INSERT INTO `user_organization`(`organizationId`, `userId`) VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
```

It looks like the marshaling of these ids are not working.

Help is appreciated